# I am getting warning for generating srandom(time(NULL))

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    srandom (time(NULL)); // **warning! implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') 'to unsigned int' **

    _number= random() % 100 +1;

    NSLog(@"random number is %d",_number);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oh well thank you i got the answer @rmaddy . It exist previously sorry for the inconvenience :)